# How can I detect plugin added and removed in Jenkins so I can improve the default output from the plugin jobConfigHistory?

Tags: bash, logging, groovy, backup, jenkins-plugins

I really love the jobConfigHistory plugin. Its diffs are so helpful.

I noticed that when I add or delete a plugin which requires no configuration, nothing is noticed by the plugin. Since plugin CRUD is often a source of pain and agony, I would love to be able to capture that information into my archiving. It would be most nifty if I could capture the version of the plugin as well, but even just the existence, just the add/delete would be really great. I didn't see it in the Jenkins System log.

One could periodically monitor the JenkinsHome/plugins folder, but is there an easier way? 
thank you!